# How to change "Available on backorder" text in woocommerce cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[image]

I want to change "Available on backorder" to another text

```
function change_specific_availability_text( $availability ) {

    $targeted_text = __( 'Available on backorder', 'woocommerce' );
    $targeted_text2 = __('In stock (can be backordered)', 'woocommerce');
    $targeted_text3 = __('Available on backorder', 'woocommerce');

    if ($availability[ 'class' ] == 'available-on-backorder' && $availability[ 'availability' ] == $targeted_text) {

        $availability[ 'availability' ] = __( '預購款  |  Backorder Item', 'your-theme-textdomain' );

    }
    
     if ($availability[ 'class' ] == 'in-stock' && $availability[ 'availability' ] == $targeted_text2) {

        $availability[ 'availability' ] = __( '現貨  |  Readystock Item', 'your-theme-textdomain' );

    }
    


    return $availability;

}


add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'change_specific_availability_text', 20, 1 );
```

Previously I use the code above to change backorder message in the product page, but I can't change the text inside the cart even I add one more class "backorder_notification" into the function

[image]

Comment: Use woocommerce_get_availability_text  filter :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of what you're doing, you can filter the availability text using the woocommerce filter `woocommerce_get_availability_text`  This filter passes the Product Object as the second param.  You can add other conditions as your needs require.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'filter_product_availability_text', 10, 2 );
function filter_product_availability_text( $availability_text, $product ) {
    // Check if product status is on backorder
    if ($product->get_stock_status() === 'onbackorder') {
        $availability_text = __( 'Your Custom Text Here', 'your-text-domain' );
    }
    return $availability_text;
}
```

Comment: For me in Woocommerce 7.1.1. this only changes the text on the product page and not in the cart.