# Change "Backorder allowed" text on cart and checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have managed to change the "backorder allowed" text on catalog and product pages using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74835978/change-frontend-text-for-backorder-allowed).

However, I would also like to change the "backorder allowed" text on cart page (and possibly on checkout, though I haven't seen it on checkout). The [accepted solution for a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69835311/how-to-change-available-on-backorder-text-in-woocommerce-cart) doesn't work (anymore).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to my `functions.php` worked for me:

```
/* --- Out of stock (Backorder) message ON CART PAGE --- */
function custom_cart_item_backorder_notification( $html, $product_id ){
    $html = '<p class="backorder_notification">' . esc_html__( 'My custom text', 'storefront' ) . '</p>';
    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_backorder_notification', 'custom_cart_item_backorder_notification', 10, 2 );
```